# Cardinalities of the intervals $(-1,1)$ and $[-1,1]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have the set $A=(-1,1)$ and the set $B=[-1,1]$.
Prove or disprove that $|A|=|B|$.

Can anyone help give a formal proof to this? I've been stuck on it for a while.

Comment: It’s probably easiest to use the [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) (if you’re allowed to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @EikeSchuite's suggestion: we can inject $A$ into $B$ with $x\mapsto x$, & $B$ into $A$ with $x\mapsto x/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ both have Lebesgue measure $1$, and necessarily have the same cardinality. If you are not comfortable with the notion of Lebesgue measure, then you need to exibit a bijection between $A$ and $B$.